# Copy text and border from Word to MS Paint

Tags: microsoft-word, copy-paste, microsoft-paint

I have a Word document with a border. When I copy and paste the whole document into MS Paint only the text is copied. The border is not copied.  I have tried this with Office 2007, 2010 and 2013.

How can I copy my text *and* the border from Word to MS Paint?

Comment: Do you need to modify the text while in Paint? If not, you could take a screenshot and paste that into Paint.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a screenshot by pressing the Print Screen key on the keyboard and then paste it in Paint.